# password checker. Something is wrong with where it checks uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: python-3.x

I have this password checker that gives you one point each time you use a captital letter or a lowercase letter. here is the code.

```
def write_password(): 
    points = 0 
    askpassword = input("enter in a password. only use the chasricters")
    #char = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"#
    #askpassword = "qwe"#testing askpassword
    chars = ["qwertyuiop","asdfghjkl", 
   "zxcvbnm","QWERTYUIOP","ASDFGHJKL","ZXCVBNM",]
    #counts consectutive numbers
    triples = []
    for char in chars:
        for i in range(len(char)-2):
            triples.append(char[i:i+3])
    input_string = askpassword.strip().lower()
    for triple in triples:
        if triple in input_string:
           points += -5
    # checks to see wather or not password has more than 8 charicters
    for char in askpassword:
        if char in askpassword:
            if len (askpassword) >= 8:
                points += 1
    #checks to see if password has a capital letter            
            for chars in askpassword:
                if (askpassword.isupper()):
                    points = points + 1
   # checks to see if password has any lowercase letters                 
                if (askpassword.islower()):
                    points = points + 1                
                else:
                    print("no points")
    print("this password is worth",points,"points")

write_password()
```

each time I put a lowercase in or a upper case in or booth, i get as an output. how many inputs i put in, squared. (e.g. input = As. my output is 4 points)

Comment: Why are you converting your input_string to lower?
    input_string = askpassword.strip().lower()

Comment: Why is your length check inside a loop? Why are the upper/lower checks inside _nested_ loops?

Comment: not really sure. I just thought I needed to do that.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How would I make it not the square the input?

Comment: Work through the logic of your last `for` loop by hand. That should show you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  Python has a library called "string" with all the lower/upper case letters.  You can define your own but why not just use it while it's already there.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

>>> def checkpassword (passwd):
...     points = 0
...     if len (passwd) >= 8:
...         points += 1
...         for char in passwd:
...             if char in string.ascii_letters:
...                 points += 1
...     
...     print ('Your password has a score of: ', points)
...     
>>> 
>>> checkpassword('Abdzf')
Your password has a score of:  0
>>> checkpassword('Abdzf2fdadf')
Your password has a score of:  11
>>> len ('Abdzf2fdadf')
11
```

If you want user's input, you can do it like so:

```
>>> def checkpassword ():
...     points = 0
...     passwd = input ('Enter a password: ')
...     [...] # Rest of the code goes here
```

Don't forget!  Even though I only have 10 characters excluding the digits, but my score is 11.  The extra point was from the length of the password being greater or equal to 8 assuming this is what you wanted.